# Best way to finding the weather Update of Current Location in Android

Tags: android, weather

What is the Best way to findout the weather Updates of my current location. Is there any good articles to follow. I have just tried this [link](http://www.anddev.org/android_weather_forecast_-_google_weather_api_-_description-t337.html). But it wont work for me. Please provide good article or sample. 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lokesh

If you already know how to how to find your location's name (city or area) from GPS, just try my example here:

https://github.com/zh-wang/YWeatherGetter4a .

You just need a city name or area name to get its current weather.

If you do not know it, check the following code

```
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String cityName = "";
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Out.d("Found city: ", addresses.get(0).getLocality());
        cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    }
```

Best Regards,
Zhenghong Wang

Comment: What is "location" here? How about I don't know my location? I mean I used your library in yahoo weather and it can't find city name by wifi. could you help me?